# Complex layouts with vue.js in laravel

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, layout, vue-konva

i am currently solving how to aproach very complex layouts like on the picture.
i will need to dynamicaly change colors of each element and dynamicaly show data in some of them.

Can anyone suggest how to aproach this?
So far i am thinking about using this https://konvajs.org/

[layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb1qV.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement it.

Probably the simplest way is to just draw such shapes with SVG.
Or you can try to use `vue-konva` or any other drawing library.